# Dell Inspiron N5010 doesn't resume from suspend

Tags: 11.10, suspend

I have freshly installed Ubuntu 11.10. When I suspend my system, (a Dell Inspiron N5010) and try to start it again, it just shows a lit up black screen.

Please somebody help because as it is there  is no option for sleep. So you can't save your work and turn off the laptop.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score -3):

You can try play around with pm-suspend utility, look what's the hardware shipped with your computer and then man pm-suspend for tips & tricks on suspending with your hardware configuration.

Once you found the right combination you may try editing suspend script and customize it to your needs.

Comment: I accidentally removed the whole pm-utils package and now can't login to the system.Any help on that?